# QueryDSL doesn't generate QType for specific entity

Tags: mongodb, jpa, spring-data, querydsl

Really confused about this. I'm using  `Spring Data MongoAnnotationProcessor` to generate `QTypes` for my domain models. Those `mongo` models happen to use some other models from a dependency that are `jpa models`. Even though I'm using the mongo processor, QueryDSL ends up generating `QTypes` for these jpa annotated `@Entities` *except* for a specific one. I tried comparing it to the other generated entities but didn't find any huge differences.

Here is the entity:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import base.lexicon.model.Literal;
import base.lexicon.model.Sport;
import base.lexicon.model.Tournament;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;
import org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Cache(
    usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE,
    region = "base.lexicon.model.Category"
)
@SequenceGenerator(
    name = "CATEGORY_SEQ",
    sequenceName = "CATEGORY_SEQ",
    allocationSize = 1
)
public class Category implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6989006403439170511L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
        generator = "CATEGORY_SEQ"
    )
    @Column(
        name = "CATEGORY_ID"
    )
    private int id;
    private String description;
    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "category"
    )
    @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
    @Cache(
        usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE,
        region = "base.lexicon.model.Category.tournaments"
    )
    @XmlTransient
    private List<Tournament> tournaments;
    @ManyToOne
    @ForeignKey(
        name = "FK_SPORT_CATEGORY"
    )
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "SPORT_ID",
        nullable = false
    )
    @XmlTransient
    private Sport sport;
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany
    @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
    @Cache(
        usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE,
        region = "base.lexicon.model.Category.literals"
    )
    @JoinTable(
        name = "CATEGORY_LITERAL",
        joinColumns = {            @JoinColumn(
                name = "CATEGORY_ID",
                referencedColumnName = "CATEGORY_ID"
            )},
        inverseJoinColumns = {            @JoinColumn(
                name = "LITERAL_ID",
                referencedColumnName = "LITERAL_ID"
            )}
    )
    private Set<Literal> literals;

    public Category() {
    }

    public int getCategoryId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public List<Tournament> getTournaments() {
        if(this.tournaments == null) {
            this.tournaments = new ArrayList();
        }

        return this.tournaments;
    }

    public void setTournaments(List<Tournament> tournaments) {
        if(tournaments != null) {
            Iterator var2 = tournaments.iterator();

            while(var2.hasNext()) {
                Tournament tournament = (Tournament)var2.next();
                if(tournament.getCategory() == null) {
                    tournament.setCategory(this);
                }
            }

            this.tournaments = tournaments;
        }

    }

    public Set<Literal> getLiterals() {
        if(this.literals == null) {
            this.literals = new HashSet();
        }

        return this.literals;
    }

    public void setLiterals(Set<Literal> literals) {
        this.literals = literals;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Sport getSport() {
        return this.sport;
    }

    public void setSport(Sport sport) {
        this.sport = sport;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(this == o) {
            return true;
        } else if(!(o instanceof Category)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            Category category = (Category)o;
            if(this.id != category.id) {
                return false;
            } else {
                if(this.description != null) {
                    if(this.description.equalsIgnoreCase(category.description)) {
                        return this.sport != null?this.sport.equals(category.sport):category.sport == null;
                    }
                } else if(category.description == null) {
                    return this.sport != null?this.sport.equals(category.sport):category.sport == null;
                }

                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result = this.id;
        result = 31 * result + (this.description != null?this.description.toLowerCase().hashCode():0);
        result = 31 * result + (this.sport != null?this.sport.hashCode():0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Does it contain any annotation or other thing that blocks the processor from generating it?